# ZF2 Action Returns 302 Redirect Instead of 200 OK When Opening Modal View

Tags: php, zend-framework2, php-7.4

I'm encountering an issue in a Zend Framework 2 (ZF2) application where a specific action, meant to display content in a modal, redirects to the homepage (/) with a 302 status, both when triggered by a button click and when accessed directly via the browser. This occurs despite expecting a 200 OK response to render the modal view.

Here's the relevant action in my controller:

```
public function deletelisteAction() {
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTerminal(true);
    $Nume = $this->params()->fromRoute('Nume', 0);
    if (!$Nume) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('parametres');
    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $del = $request->getPost('del', 'Non');
        if ($del == 'Oui') {
            $Nume = $request->getPost('Nume');
            $this->getListTable()->deleteListe($Nume);
            $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('La suppression a été faite avec succées.');
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('parametres');
        }
    }

    $viewModel->Nume = $Nume;
    $viewModel->list = $this->getListTable()->getListe($Nume);
    return $viewModel;
}
```

I've tried setting the status code to 200 directly in the action using `$this->response->setStatusCode(200)`, but it doesn't seem to affect the outcome. The issue persists on the cloud server, but it works as expected locally.

**What I've checked so far:**

Session-based authentication and authorization checks are in place, but the session is active, and the user is authorized to access this action.
Route configurations are correctly set up in module.config.php.
AJAX requests include the X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest header.

**Questions:**

What could be causing this 302 redirect to occur instead of rendering the view in a modal?
Are there any ZF2-specific configurations or common pitfalls that might lead to this behavior?
Any insights or suggestions on how to debug and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.